# javascript update or add values to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

I want to add values to array. But the same values may update. for example my array is

```
[{"abc1":"123456"},{"abc2":"123456"}]
```

when is adding again  is abc1. It may update. For example in normal case

```
[{"abc1":"123456"},{"abc2":"123456"},{"abc1":"123456"}]
```

But i want

```
[{"abc2":"123456"},{"abc1":"123456"}]
```

My code

```
var categories = [],
arrIndex = {};

addOrReplace({"abc1":"125"});
addOrReplace({"abc2":"126"});
addOrReplace({"abc1":"127"});
addOrReplace({"abc3":"129"});


function addOrReplace(object) {
    var index = arrIndex[object[0]];
    console.log("index:"+object[0]);
    if(index === undefined) {
        index = categories.length;
    }
    arrIndex[object[1]] = index;
    categories[index] = object;
}

console.log(categories);
```

It not showing correct answer. 
It shows

```
[{"abc3":"129"}]
```

I want

```
[{"abc2":"126"},{"abc1":"127"},{"abc3":"129"}]
```

How it possible? Please help me?

Comment: So if I understand right, if objects with key `abc1` exists, delete it and push new value. Am I right?

Comment: If object inside array has only one key, I would suggest to have object than array. Value will be overwritten in Object

Comment: @Rajesh yes you are right.

Comment: @Rayon how it possible?

Comment: @joe — `var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
obj.a = 3;
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: @Rayon on using this array. If i want to get 2 while a is 1. how it possible to array filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) ans plice the object from categories if the index is found, then push the new object to `categories`.

```js
function addOrReplace(object) {
    var key = Object.keys(object)[0],
        index = categories.findIndex(o => key in o);

    if (index !== -1) {
        categories.splice(index, 1);
    }
    categories.push(object)
}

var categories = [];

addOrReplace({ abc1: "125"});
console.log(categories);
addOrReplace({ abc2: "126"});
console.log(categories);
addOrReplace({ abc1: "127"});
console.log(categories);
addOrReplace({ abc3: "129"});
console.log(categories);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var categories = new Map(); 

    addOrReplace({"abc1":"125"});
    addOrReplace({"abc2":"126"});
    addOrReplace({"abc1":"127"});
    addOrReplace({"abc3":"129"});


    function addOrReplace(object) {
       for (var name in object)
             categories[name] = object;
    }

    console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories = [],
arrIndex = {};

addOrReplace({"abc1":"125"});
addOrReplace({"abc2":"126"});
addOrReplace({"abc1":"127"});
addOrReplace({"abc3":"129"});


function addOrReplace(object) {
    for(var c in categories){
        if(Object.keys(categories[c])[0] == Object.keys(object)[0]){
            categories.splice(c,1)
        }
    }
    categories.push(object)
}

console.log(categories);
//[{"abc2":"126"},{"abc1":"127"},{"abc3":"129"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would be finally using the final data but in case you are looking for the uniqueness, i would like to recommend to go for `object hash` instead of array.

Initially :

```
{
    "abc1" : "123456",
    "abc2" : "123456"
}
```

If you now add `{ "abc1" : "some_other_value" }`.

```
{
    "abc1" : "some_other_value",
    "abc2" : "123456"
}
```

You can also check if the value exist already or not using `if(objectHash('abc1'))`.

It can save you from extra traversal and would overwrite values if already present.